# How to convert "m years n months" into "m*12+ n months"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file who has a column "remaining lease" of a house, which are expressed in m years and n months, which I want to convert into months.

Below is how it looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh4Nc.png

Is there a way to do in pandas, or in excel?

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly post samples of input and expected output in form of text only and NOT in any other forms. Also wrap your samples in CODE TAGS and let us know then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the map Function for pandas.Series objects. Following code could do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

def lease_string_to_months(time):
    split_string = time.split(' ')
    months = 12*int(split_string[0]) + int(split_string[2])
    return months

filepath = './example.csv' # write the filepath here as a string

house_lease = new pd.read_csv(filepath)
new_header = house_lease.iloc[0] 
house_lease = house_lease[1:] 
house_lease.columns = new_header 
house_lease['remaining_lease'].map(lease_string_to_months)
```

I modified the code so it would fit your posted dataset, as the first row consists of the headers for your data. pd.Series.map takes a series, a dictionary or a function with one argument as a parameter.